# See what apps I have installed with the facebook SDK

Tags: sdk

Is there a way to check on my rooted phone what apps use the Facebook (or just any) SDK?

Comment: You can check your apps using https://exodus-privacy.eu.org/en/page/what/. They try to identify trackers based on the strings in the app. However if an app is heavily obfuscated this will fail.

Comment: There are several [privacy checkers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admodules) (link goes to my site) which can assist you here: Exodus Privacy (as mentioned by Robert) for non-paid apps available on Play, ClassyShark3xodus and TrackerControl for apps on-device are the ones I'd recommend as they come free of trackers themselves, Appbrain is quite good as well (comes with a single ad module by Appbrain itself).